# Android Button Constraints and Screen Sizes

Tags: android

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.hp.buttonconstraints.MainActivity">


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnTwo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/questionBacksplash"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/questionBacksplash"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnSeven"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnFive"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/answerBtnSeven"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnSeven"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/answerBtnEight"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnThree"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnEight"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

     <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnEight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/answerBtnSix"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnSix"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnSix"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnEight"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/answerBtnFour"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/answerBtnFour"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnFour"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_rectangle"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnSix"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/answerBtnTwo"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/questionBacksplash"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answerBtnOne"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
```

..................................................

I am trying to add some buttons to a page in constraint mode but I need them to resize across different screens. It appears button 1 is holding a 148dp width which is suitable for the Galaxy Nexus but not the Nexus 4. The Nexus 4 needs to be 158dp. However when I resize the button in the Nexus 4 layout it then shrinks in the Galaxy layout. Can someone advise how I get around this

Answer (score 2):

Why u don't give `android:layout_width  android:layout_height` to your buttons!!give them size from `dimens` and use different `dimens` from resources to different screen size

Comment: Thanks have now added dimensions

Comment: please if answer is correct,mark as correct))Thanks